# How to delete all entries from list?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to delete all entries from list using angular js. I have two directives I communicate between two directive suing shared service. I am able to add the entry in my list .

I want to delete my list when I click on delete button. I blank my array, but I blank my array on service so it is not reflected on my view. How to blank my list?

Here is my code

> https://jsfiddle.net/8fjhLqnw/4/

I delete like that

```js
vm.delete = function() {
   vm.data = [];
}
```

It is not reflecting on my view

Answer (score 1):

For deleting all the entries from a list in Angularjs, you can do something like this

```
$scope.students.splice( $scope.students.indexOf(student), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vm.delete = function() {
    vm.data.length = 0;
}
```

Because you use `f.data = sharedData.data` to put the data into the scope of the controller, the will share the same array instance, so modifications on `sharedData.data` will be seen on `f.data`, as they are the same.
By `sharedData.data = []` you assign a new instance of an array to `sharedData.data`.
From that point, `f.data` and `sharedData.data` are separate instances, any modification done on `sharedData.data` will leave `f.data` unaffected.

Another way to workaround this:

```
.controller('f', function($scope, sharedData) {
    this.data = sharedData; // and not this.data = sharedData.data
})
```

and reference the data as `f.data.data`. This way you can put in new array instances, because you access it directly through `sharedData`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `vm.data.length = 0;` to clear the array. If you assign a new array, it will not be bound to the view.